# Getting the selected item from a ListView

Tags: android

Please Help me for getting the selected Item from a ListView. Items for the ListView are getting from a xml file. Elements of the ListView are filled up by the adapter(adpter contains ImageView and textView). I only need the TextView content from the ListView.By using the onItemClick i get only the index of the item.

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

Using [getSelectedItem()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getSelectedItem()) is the correct thing to do. You get a null value back when no item is selected.

Comment: I am getting null value while using getSelectedItem().

Answer (score 0):

If I remember true, `getSelectedItem()` just use if your Activity is `ListActivity`.

In normal Activity, and you add a component `ListView`. here is an example code, wish you can follow it :

```
private ListView listContainer; public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.view);
        listContainer = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listContainer);
        listContainer.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adView, View target, int postion, long id) {
                alert("notice", "you have selected: " + id);            }

        });

        protected void alertbox(String title, String mymessage) {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage(mymessage).setTitle(title).setCancelable(true)
        .setNeutralButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton){}  
         }).show();  
    }
```